# QT: Creating menu items in a loop behave differently

Tags: python, qt

I'm having this weird problem, I'm creating file menu action items from a list that I have. It displays properly but behaves the wrong way.

Here's an example snippet of my code:

```
self.dMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&Fruit')

for entry in ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry']:
   item = QAction(QIcon(), entry, self)
   item.triggered.connect(lambda: print(item.text())) #Prints the menu action's text when clicked
   self.dMenu.addAction(item)
```

In the file menu it shows up as:

- apple
- banana
- orange
- strawberry

When I click on the item it should display the action item's text but it always prints `strawberry` regardless of which I press. (Even though it shows the text as `apple` for example.)

I also tried creating an array of QAction menu items to see if that would solve the problem.

```
self.dMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&Fruit')
actionItems = {}

for entry in ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry']:
   actionItems[entry] = QAction(QIcon(), entry, self)
   actionItems[entry].triggered.connect(lambda: print(actionItems[entry].text())) #Prints the menu action's text when clicked
   self.dMenu.addAction(actionItems[entry])
```

Same results though. I'm not really sure what's causing all the action items to behave the same even though each is being created as it's own instance. I initially set the action to just print `entry` but that didn't do anything, I was hoping printing the instance's text would fix the problem but it seems like that didn't work either.

Edit: Just want to mention the array I'm using is much larger and is changing frequently so I can't just hard code each entry in the menu.

Comment: use `item.triggered.connect(lambda checked, it = item : print(it.text()))`

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem!  It didn't cross my mind that lambda was the source of the error.

Comment: Read the answer of the question that you mark as duplicate, there clearly explains it, but instead of QPushButton you have a QAction